# HTML+CSS Sidebar next to centered content

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML-CSS layout like this:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 5px;
}

#stripe {
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div id="stripe">
      <main>
      <p>some content</p>
      </main>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This gives me a centered stripe for my content.

Now I want to put a table of contents to the right (or maybe also to the left) of this centered stripe. It should be in an absolute/fixed position, with a slight horizontal distance to the centered stripe. The text should expand over the whole right (or left) of the stripe to the border of the body. If the text is longer than that, it should wrap (i.e. make linebreaks).

A good example is [here](https://castel.dev/post/lecture-notes-3/) (scroll down a bit). Unfortunately I couldn't figure out how he does it by inspecting the HTML/CSS.

I have tried for example the following, but the width is wrong so that the text doesn't break:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 5px;
}

#stripe {
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#toc {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div id="toc">
      <p>this text is so long and it doesn't break which is bad</p>
    </div>
    <div id="stripe">
      <main>
      <p>this</p>
      <p>is</p>
      <p>an</p>
      <p>example</p>
      <p>for</p>
      <p>some</p>
      <p>cool</p>
      <p>content</p>
      </main>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If anybody could help me achieve this, that would be amazing! Thank you so much.

Comment: Not seeing anything centered. Not seeing any stripe. Post a [mcve] please.

Comment: You should have gone fullscreen, because the width was 700px. I reduced it to 200px and set a background color so it's better visible.

Comment: Now I also added something that I tried.

Comment: In the example you provided it's done by calculating the position and the width: `transform: translateX(calc(-100% - 2em)) translateY(4em);` and `width: calc(-4em - 340px + 50vw);` where 340px is half the width of the center div.

Comment: Thanks! That's indeed very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a custom variable for the width of centered-div and then width of sidebar will be equal to:

{(100% - width_center_div) / 2 - gap }

```
:root {
  --width: 200px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 5px;
}

#stripe {
  margin: auto;
  width: var(--width);
  background-color: yellow;
}

#toc {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc((100dvw - var(--width))/2 - 1rem);
  top: 0;
  // For right sidebar use right:0; instead of left
  left:0;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think that should somehow work, though it's not the cleanest solution. I also can't see how to make this work for the right side. I think there must be a better solution...

Comment: For the right side instead of `left:0;`  add 
 `right:0;` in the sidebar.

Comment: Not the cleanest solution? You just had to add four lines of css. The custom variable is recommended for maintainability, you can put the value of width directly but it's a bad practice, you will run into issues later.

Comment: I ended up doing it this way. With "clean" I just meant that there might be native solution without calculating your self any widths, but that it's done automatically because the next element begins.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve that by using `grid`. Defining 2 columns one for the `aside` and another one for the `main` content. Like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-moore-4zqccp?file=/index.html

html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <aside>
      <ul>
        <li>Element 1</li>
        <li>Element 2</li>
        <li>Element 3</li>
        <li>Element 4</li>
      </ul>
    </aside>
    <main>
      <p>This is the main content for this webpage</p>
      <p>This is the main content for this webpage</p>
      <p>This is the main content for this webpage</p>
      <p>This is the main content for this webpage</p>
      <p>This is the main content for this webpage</p>
      <p>This is the main content for this webpage</p>
      <p>This is the main content for this webpage</p>
      <p>This is the main content for this webpage</p>
      <p>This is the main content for this webpage</p>
      <p>This is the main content for this webpage</p>
      <p>This is the main content for this webpage</p>
      <p>This is the main content for this webpage</p>
      <p>This is the main content for this webpage</p>
      <p>This is the main content for this webpage</p>
      <p>This is the main content for this webpage</p>
      <p>This is the main content for this webpage</p>
      <p>This is the main content for this webpage</p>
      <p>This is the main content for this webpage</p>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  gap: 10px;
  min-height: 10vh;
}

aside {
  border: 1px solid red;
  align-self: center;
}

main {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

I hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: I thought about using grid. But I still need to center the middle column and it must have a fixed width. Unfortunately your solution provides neither.

Answer (score 0):

Because the question is asking for a lot and doesn't give an example of what it wants to achieve, I will go based off what examples have been given.

In html there are different ways to make text break, the most common is probably the `<p>` element itself. Because the `<p>` has `display: block`, it will automatically take all available width unless told otherwise, because of this, if you declare multiple `<p>` elements, they will all be on different lines, one after the other. More information about `display: block` and other display values can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.php). Another way to do this, is using the `<br>` element, or, "break line" element. This element will take all the available width, creating a separation between the elements on the top and bottom, however, because the element is transparent by default, it does not appear that anything is there. More information about this element can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp). There are probably more ways to do this too, but the final example that I will give, is the one I think you are looking for.

It appears that you want to make the text break only when the end of the line has been reached. Luckily, there is a css property that you can use, called `overflow-wrap`. This property tells the browser how to break text when it gets to the end of a line. The default value is `normal` which does absolutely nothing to the text. The value we want to use is `break-word`, which, as the name implies, will break the word when it reaches the end of the line. More information about this property and its values can be found [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow-wrap/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I did provide an example of what I want to achieve. See the link in my post.

Comment: Yes, I know, I stated clearly the plural of example, it shows what the text should look like, but doesn't provide other examples of what the rest should look like, because this I stated clearly, "I will go based off what examples have been given."

Comment: I still don't get what you mean? I provided a link to a page that provides *exactly* what I want. So I *did* give an example of what I want to achieve, and you are just denying it. (If you are asking for *code* for what I want to achieve, well, that's what I'm asking for.)

Comment: No, as I said in my last comment, you did not provide *examples*, you did provide an *example* of what you wanted the "center stripe" to look like. However, you did provide an image to aid in the deciphering of the following "Now I want to put a table of contents to the right (or maybe also to the left) of this centered stripe. It should be in an absolute/fixed position, with a slight horizontal distance to the centered stripe. The text should expand over the whole right (or left) of the stripe to the border of the body. If the text is longer than that, it should wrap (i.e. make linebreaks).".

Comment: 1. In your post you write "the question [...] doesn't give an *example* of what it wants to achieve", which is the singular of example.
2. Once again: I *did* provide an example of what I want to achieve, *including* the table of contents. Here is the link once more: https://castel.dev/post/lecture-notes-3/ Scroll down and you see a table of contents. :)

Comment: Correct, I stated that it doesn't give an example of what the full thing should look like, hence the what it wants to achieve part. What part is confusing?

Comment: The third time: The website I linked to provides *exactly* what I want. In other words, this is *what I want to achieve*. Hence this *is* an example of what I want to achieve. Hence I *did* provide an example of what I want to achieve.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254138/discussion-between-eliasciur-and-johann-birnick).

Comment: So you are saying that was all you wanted to achieve? I understood you wanted to put a table of contents to the left or right, which is why I said that you did not include an **example of what the full thing should look like**.

Comment: Yes but I'm able to generate a table of contents. It's just about that I want to put some text on the side, obviously. Also, the fourth time, the link is an example of the full thing lol. (And you continue to write in the comments though you provided a chat link.)

Comment: Well then you should have just asked to create a word break when the text reaches the end of the line.

Comment: No, everybody here understands what I mean except you. ;)